# Firebase console user access control

Tags: user-management, firebase, google-cloud-identity

Im looking for a way to have user management (creation, management, roles assigments, etc.) for Firebase console users (not app code level control).  So far I've been testing solutions to this situation by integrating Microsoft as a provider in Firebase and using Google Cloud Platform with Cloud Identity but it all seems that these solutions are aiming at Firebase code level access control but not to Firebase console user management.  Our Security Department is asking for this to let use Firebase since we have just local accounts in Firebase. So far all I have found on the internet talks about app code access control.  Does this is possible in Firebase or the Firebase console user management does not have an integration with external Id Provider?

Thanks in advanced.
Walter